# Concatenate values in sequence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have numbers and combination of numbers and characters, but not sequence. If these are in sequence, then the result should be like below. If I have data like 
below.
the values are C 1,C 2,C 5,C 7,T 1,T 5,T 6,T 55

Need the result like
C 1-C 2,C 5,C 7,T 1,T 5-T 6,T 55

no spaces after character.

Comment: Could you please show your sample in data in tabular form.

Comment: How is this SQL Server related?

Comment: Do you have 2 columns? 1 for the alphabet and another for the number?

Comment: 1
2
3
11
12
13
C1
C2
C5
C7
T1
T5
T6
T55

Comment: @ wewesthemenace, no single column only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SQL statement like following:

```
SELECT 
   STUFF( (SELECT ',' + CAST(FNAME AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                             FROM OldTable
                             ORDER BY LNAME desc
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            1, 1, '')
```

Here is updated version of query provided by wewesthemenace:

```
WITH CteSplit(letter, number) AS(
    SELECT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(FNAME, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', FNAME) -1))),
        CAST(RIGHT(FNAME, LEN(FNAME) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', FNAME) + 1) AS INT)
    FROM OldTable
)
,Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = number - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY letter ORDER BY number)
    FROM CteSplit
)
,CteFinal AS(
    SELECT
        letter,
        startNumber = MIN(number),
        endNumber = MAX(number)
    FROM Cte
    GROUP BY letter, RN
)
SELECT
    STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + letter + ' ' + CAST(startNumber AS VARCHAR(MAX)) +
                CASE
                    WHEN startNumber = endNumber 
                        THEN ''
                    ELSE 
                        '-' + letter + ' ' + CAST(endNumber AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                END
            FROM CteFinal
            ORDER BY letter, startNumber, endNumber
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
  ,1, 1, '')
```

Upgrades:

1. We do not relies on spaces after characters, search of number instead
2. Leading and finishing spaces near the characters will be ignored

Comment: My result like 1-3,11-13,C1-C2,C5,C7,T1,T5-T6,T55 Input like 1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, C1, C2, C5, C7, T1, T5, T6, T55. Thanks

Comment: I see. So you can use a cursor to iterate all records sequentially and remember previous value. Then, if text of current and next are equal and digit part of current = previous +1 then we can unite them and keep in mind the beginning of the sequence and if the next one will be previously + 2 and so on we can add it to the current sequence.
I'll write you query which can do it after an hour - have to go out now.

Comment: I've updated query and here is your results: C1-C2,C5,C7,T1,T5-T6,T55

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
    val VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
('C 1'), ('C 2'), ('C 5'),
('T 1'), ('T 5'), ('T 6'), ('T 55');


val
----------
C 1
C 2
C 5
T 1
T 5
T 6
T 55
```

Final Query:

```
;WITH CteSplit(letter, number) AS(
    SELECT
        LEFT(val, CHARINDEX(' ', val) -1),
        CAST(RIGHT(val, LEN(val) - CHARINDEX(' ', val) + 1) AS INT)
    FROM tbl
)
,Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = number - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY letter ORDER BY number)
    FROM CteSplit
)
,CteFinal AS(
    SELECT
        letter,
        startNumber = MIN(number),
        endNumber = MAX(number)
    FROM Cte
    GROUP BY letter, RN
)
SELECT
    STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + letter + ' ' + CAST(startNumber AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                CASE
                    WHEN startNumber = endNumber 
                        THEN ''
                    ELSE 
                        '-' + letter + ' ' + CAST(endNumber AS VARCHAR(10))
                END
            FROM CteFinal
            ORDER BY letter, startNumber, endNumber
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,1, 1, '')
```

**RESULT**

```
-------------------------------
C 1-C 2,C 5,T 1,T 5-T 6,T 55
```